# How to automate azure ad authentication or MFA using selenium c#/ Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, specflow, multi-factor-authentication

I have an application to write automaton tests for, but all the applications are connected to login through azure AD.
After entering username and password, it sends a notification to my MFA mobile app to approve.

How can I automate this using c# selenium . I am using specflow for my automation.
Or in Any other language or framework is also helpful.

Comment: Can you set this user up with e-mail for their second factor authentication? If so, maybe you could make web service calls to the e-mail server?